# JQuery Mobile Styles Only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-mobile

I like JQuery Mobile, but I have many custom Javascript in my page that are not compatible with JQuery Mobile.

Everything in my page works fine, but when I add the JQuery Mobile library they break out and I tried fixing stuff around but there's a lot and didn't succeed.

Now the only thing I really need from JQuery is basically the styles. This is basically the styles for:
- Textboxes
- Buttons
- On/Off switcher (I think that's a radio button right? It'll be great if I can grab the switcher left and right, but if that doesn't work without the JS file I don't mind using only its style without the animation as long as I can switch it on and off by tapping).
- DropDown Lists.

That's pretty much everything I need from JQuery Mobile in my pages, I don't need anything else like the Ajax stuff, Pages & the many other things that JQuery Mobile provides.

I tried to attach the CSS to the JQuery Mobile without the JS file, and tried to locate the necessary classes for the controls above, but they are not appearing right!

Can you guys tell me if there is a way to apply only the styles of the JQuery Mobile library? I don't need the functions.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do that. Few months ago jQuery Mobile developers created download builder. It is a tool that can customize jQuery Mobile framework thus giving you power to select only needed functionality.

Link can be found here: **[Download Builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/)**.

All you need to do is select jQuery Mobile version on the top and select needed widgets at the page bottom. Page will automatically select any other required files.

Comment: It's working great now. Took me a few minutes to set that up and integrate it within my application. Thanks again really!

Answer (score 0):

By just including the jQuery Mobile and jQuery js and css file that you used before? I understand if you used the earlier version, you need to include  the compressed, production jQuery Migrate 1.1.1 as well.
Here are the links:
http://jquerymobile.com/download/
http://jquery.com/download/

Everything is there but you can choose not to use anything from there.